# Disable chatter email notifications for community users

Tags: community, chatter

I have couple of communities - ComA & ComB (lets say). We have a tab in both the communities which allow the users to message each other.
Now the scenario is that when ComA users message ComB users, the ComB users do not receive the email notifications (which is as expected for us), but same is not true for vice versa case. The ComA users are getting emails for the messages.

How can I disable the emails for the ComA users also?

This is how we are posting:
// send post
ConnectApi.FeedElement feedElement =
ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(null, (ConnectApi.FeedElementInput) feedItemInput);

Answer (score 0):

Have you disabled chatter email notifications for NetworkMember records?

These are users that are members of specific sites.

Once you've disabled for existing users, you'd then need to default that when new users are created going forward.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000338320&type=1

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000334954&type=1

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000336538&type=1